# Trying to format a laptop with no DVD Rom

Tags: windows-xp, windows-installation

I am trying to format a laptop but the DVD Drive is not Working. I tried booting from a USB but even though I have it on the top of list it skips it. I tried disabling all other boot devices and leaving only the Removable Device but still nothing. In case it matters the Laptop is a Fujitsu Siemens Amilo 1667G

***EDIT
The USB flash drive I am using is USB 2.0. Also I tried pressing f12 and selecting removable drive manually from the boot menu. Removable Drive did not appear

Question: Is it possible to mount the iso and install windows from within windows, or is there another option?

Comment: What are you using in the USB Drive?

Comment: Are you using a USB 2 or did you accidentally try to boot from an USB 3 port. Depending on your model the latter might not work.

Comment: On some BIOSes, a bootable USB flash drive is not listed as a **Removable Device**, but is listed under **Hard Drives**

Comment: @Hennes it usb 2.0 (completely sure, just checked)

Comment: @sawdust in BIOS setup removable disk is there, in boot menu (when I press f12) it is not there

Comment: You don't happen to be plugging your USB in your USB3.0 port do you? (Just had to ask as I had that issue in my workplace USB connected to USB3.0 port are not detected as part of boot from USB / hard drive)

Comment: @Darius nop, and since many ask I will edit my post :D

Comment: @JohnDemetriou This is just a random thought... since you said you 'burn' the ISO into USB.. any chance it is considering the USB as a bootable CD instead of removable disk / hard disk...? So maybe after you press f12, just start trying out all the options... ? (and also test the USB on a different PC/laptop maybe after burning it is no longer bootable / detected)

Comment: @Darius I will try that but in other occasions when I booted from USB i selected removable device not CD/DVD, but I will try it

Comment: @JohnDemetriou, not to keep flogging a dead horse, but when you clarified about USB 2.0, you specified that the USB _drive_ is 2.0, while the questions were about the actual USB _port_ on your computer. Are you sure the port itself is not USB 3.0?

Comment: Does Windows boot and how far does it get? (I understand this is XP) Do you have by any chance another similar computer?

Comment: I suppose you don't have floppy drive, right?

Comment: I'm coming late to the party but... maybe your computer can boot from the network. If you have another computer it can act as a startup-server after which you can format, reinstall etc.. xp on the laptop. There are several tutorials on the net depending if you just want to format or completely reinstall xp. [This is one](http://www.ccboot.com/network-boot.htm). Not exactly what you asked for but it can work if usb and cdrom don't work.

Comment: @Rik Can you write a full answer with a bit more details? If I remember correctly (I do not have the laptop in my hands now, but I can get it back) network did show up in the boot menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i understand it, booting from DVD-Drive is not working and booting from USB is problematic. Then (without stripping the laptop apart for the harddrive) you're left with 2 options:

**Option 1**: You can (re)install Windows XP from within Windows XP. Provided XP does boot correctly. You don't have the option to format the drive but `Windows`, `Program Files` and `Documents and Settings` will be moved to a `WINDOWS.OLD` and you'll get a clean install.

You don't need to mount an ISO to install Windows from Windows. All you need is the `I386`-directory from CD (You can copy it over a network-share or if the USB is working for files via USB.) copy it to `C:\I386` and run `C:\I386\winnt32.exe`. Downside is your harddrive needs to be big enough to hold the new installation and the old WINDOWS.OLD. Also you need to do some cleaning afterwards to see what you can delete from that WINDOWS.OLD. And it is probably best to run a defragmenter afterwards.

**edit**:
Windows XP does not create an old WINDOWS.OLD like i expected.
With the `New Installation (Advanced)` Windows will install **over** the current installation. It **will** ask to delete the current `C:\WINDOWS` but it will leave `Program Files` and `Documents and Settings` intact. (not exactly a *clean* install)

**Option 2**: This one is a bit more difficult. **Booting from the network**.

**How it works**:

When you boot from your network-adapter it checks for a DHCP-server. The DHCP-server gives an IP **and** should tell the client where to get the bootloader (not all DHCP-server can do this). That bootloader is then fetched using TFTP. After that the bootloader should load the OS. This OS should be "network-aware". Linux is "network-aware" out of the box but for Windows you'll need to use the right files. (You can't just plop an .iso in there)

**What you'll need**:

- A (small) DHCP-server capable of giving the bootloader loacation.
- A (small) FTPD-server capable of serving the bootloader itself.
- The bootloader
- The rest of the OS files ("network-aware")

For the DHCP-server and FTPD-server you could try [TFTPD32](http://tftpd32.jounin.net/) which has both in one. I also found some info on [this page](http://diddy.boot-land.net/pxe/index.htm) for setting this up.

You could also try [Ultimate Deployment Appliance](http://www.ultimatedeployment.org) which has a complete "virtual machine"-image for this setup.

Some reading material:

- [Wikipedia/Network_booting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_booting)
- [Wikipedia/Preboot_Execution_Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment)
- [NetworkBoot.Org](http://networkboot.org/fundamentals/)
- [Setup TFTPD32 with BartPE](http://www.nico-maas.de/wordpress/?p=204)
- [hanewin.net Remote-boot](http://www.hanewin.net/remote-boot.htm)
- [CCBoot](http://www.ccboot.com/network-boot.htm)

## Edit:

Neat. I just tried it, simple, with a 622C.IMG (bootable MS-DOS 6.22 floppy image).

Install (or extract) [TFTPD32](http://tftpd32.jounin.net/) to `c:\tftpd32` (I just took the .zip, no need for install, just extract to `c:\tftpd`). Download [syslinux-4.04.tar.gz](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/syslinux/syslinux-4.04.tar.gz) from [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/syslinux/). Extract `memdisk` and `pxelinux.0` (search for them) from this archive and put them in `c:\tftpd32\root`. Download [622c.zip](http://s93616405.onlinehome.us/bootdisk/622c.zip) from [bootdisk.com](http://www.bootdisk.com/bootdisk.htm) and put `622C.IMG` in `c:\tftpd32\root`. Make a `c:\tftpd32\root\pxelinux.cfg` **directory**. Put a textfile named `default` with the following content in there:

```
default boot
prompt 0
say booting...
label boot
  kernel memdisk bigraw
  append initrd=622C.IMG
```

Now start `tftpd32.exe` or `tftpd64.exe`.

In "Settings" put `C:\tftpd32\root` in the TFTP-tab and check the boxes:
[image: TFTP-tab]

Fill in the DHCP-tab and check the settings: (Boot file = pxelinux.0).
[image: DHCP-tab]

Restart TFTPD.

Now start your laptop and choose network. If all is well your laptop should boot right to the DOS-prompt. You can now format your harddrive ;-) This was just a little exercise but this can also be done with BartPE and other Windows environments.

If your laptop does not start from the network it could be that you have to disable your current DHCP-server. (This was not necessary here, both my router and desktop acted as DHCP-server and my laptop took the right IP from the DHCP from my desktop)

**Edit 2**: These steps use `pxelinux.0` to boot the laptop over the network. [These pages](http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/pxe) show you how to use `grub4dos` and `tftpd32` to boot IMG and ISO files.

Comment: I have the CD Drive Image, If I mount it, will it work the same as your first Option? I am trying to get it as simple as possible as I will explain through the phone the procedure to a friend who is abroad

Comment: With the `grub4dos` method, if the CD Drive Image is small enough to fit into memory it should work. I'm getting MEMORY OVERFLOW here if i try a big ISO image. How large is the image? I'll try a small ISO image with `pxelinux.0`.

Comment: Replacing the `.img` with a `.iso` does not work with `pxelinux.0`. With `grub4dos` it will. (But the iso should be small)

Comment: You say in the first option that I can copy the I386 folder in C and run the winnt32, which is like "upgrading" Windows. Can I simply mount the iso from within windows XP and install windows XP with the same result as your first option?

Comment: With the first option you'll have to mount the ISO and copy the I386 directory to your local harddrive. (because after reboot when Windows is going to install the mount will not be available and the copied I386 will be) If you choose to install a **new** copy during install it will move your WINDOWS etc to WINDOWS.OLD. It is a (semi) fresh install because there will be new WINDOWS, DOCUMENT AND SETTING, and PROGRAM FILES directories.

Comment: One small note of warning. Does your network adapter have special drivers or is are they included in the standard Windows XP installation. If you install Windows XP and your network adapter is not working the only way to get the drivers is internet (for which you need the network adapter ;) If your USB is still working for normal files this won't be a problem. Otherwise.... ieks. ;( So if you have special drivers copy them before doing the install.

Comment: I can use that method then (copying the I386 folder). How much Hard disk space is needed in order to do that? And I simply copy the folder and run the winnt32 and just follow windows XP installation like always?

Comment: You'll need about 1,2Gb space. 600Mb for the I386 and another 600Mb for the fact Windows will be copying them again. **But** i just tried it with an old laptop and Windows XP SP3 does **not** create a WINDOWS.OLD like i expected. It will ask you to delete the WINDOWS directory, which is not a problem, but it will leave "Program Files" and "Documents and Settings" intact which if far from a clean installation. I'm now checking why this is.

Comment: Do the applications that were installed before still work? if they do not it means the files just remained there and the registry has been renew

Comment: That depends if the application needs the registry. Windows is completely clean installed but the directories where just left behind. I'm currently trying the upgrade function but perhaps a extra partition of 700Mb is the best solution.  JourneymanGeek suggested something like that but he suggested installing to that new partition. I would create a partition with only I386 and installing (with format) to C:. (testing that next ;) I believe there is nothing of worth on the computer to backup? So a format would be fine?

Comment: The data is completely backed up, the computer does open. But is in desperate need of a format

Comment: And there is just one partition?

Comment: Currently yes. But creating an extra one is not a problem. If there is no space I will simply delete some of the backed up data

Comment: Nope, upgrade leaves everything in place. (not recommended) I will try a quick install from a small second partition.

Comment: Wow, this seems much more difficult. My first instinct was to create an extra partition from where you run WINNT32, but Windows installs temporary files in C: (and you can't change that because the /tempfile parameter needs to be the same as where Windows is going to be installed) so you can't format C: during install. If you create a big enough extra partition you can install it to that partition (exactly like JourneymanGeek suggested).

Comment: Second i looked for boot from ISO and came across [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) but after installing that they say "Windows XP"-bootloader is not supported. I expect you could use Grub-bootloaders etc. but then there is a chance your laptop becomes unbootable and then you have a problem. So you can go for the answer of JourneymanGeek or you can use my option 1 and try to clean out the "Program Files"-directory yourself after re-install.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a procedure for installing Windows XP on a computer with no CD (let's call it "the laptop").

You will need :

- A second computer running Windows XP that has a CD drive (let's call it "the desktop" )
- A Genuine copy of the Windows XP installation CD and a valid serial number

You will need to extract the hard disk from the laptop and install it on the desktop,
either as a second hard disk, or by using an enclosure to convert it
to an external USB drive. Let's assume that this disk is called `E:`. It's probably best to format this disk before you do anything, so save first any data that you want to recover. It shouldn't matter which file system you use: FAT32 or NTFS·
Do not use the fast-format method, since slow format can fix bad sectors on the disk,
even if it is, well, slow.

Insert the XP installation CD and close any pop-up window.
Let's assume that the CD is called `D:`.

In the command prompt on the desktop (maybe run as administrator) enter this command :

```
D:\I386\winnt32.exe /syspart:E: /tempdrive:E: /makelocalsource /noreboot
```

This will start the XP installer from the CD drive. The `/syspart:E:` switch tells it to make the E: drive into a system drive; `/tempdrive:E:` directs the temporary files to
that drive; `/makelocalsource` tells XP to copy all the source files to the drive so you won't need the CD any more; `/noreboot` is to not reboot after the files were copied.

After the setup completes on the desktop, eject E: and put it back in the laptop, then boot as normal. 
When you boot, Windows XP should begin installing automatically.

Comment: +1 coz I have to install third party live usb creator just to make it bootable and this made it manually.

Comment: I forgot to upvote your answer before so I did now

Answer (score 4):

I actually tried a few solutions and its kind of strange, and might take a lot of coffee time. I'd note i've had a few failed attempts, and have warned where things get dangerous. Read through the whole answer before you tried it. This particular process is safe, as long as you keep in mind why things are being done.

I basically created a second partition, installed windows there from the original partition, and used that to bootstrap the windows install back to the original partition. I've cheated a bit, and cleaned out, but not formatted the old windows partition, since its safer first, though I've posted an answer where I reformatted the drive as well.

You'll need a windows iso, 7zip and some software for resizing drives  (I used [minitools free](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) from inside windows). You'll also be using things in system properties a lot - you access this by right clicking and my computer - so get familiar with this.

[image]

First extract the contents of the windows iso using 7zip into a folder (if you have it installed - rightclick on the iso, and select "extract to" copy this into your tumbdrive. You'll need to use this more than once so keep it handy. You'll also want to keep the minitools installer here.

Install minitools on the current, working system and use that to create a new partition with free space after the current install. You want this to be at least 2.5 gb, and file system dosen't matter all that much since you will be installing a temporary copy of windows XP inside this (in theory, you could make a big partition, install windows XP here, and just work off that. We're assuming though, you want a single, large, functioning windows XP partitions, with a single pc, no external boot devices, and a windows iso. This will make you reboot once, and go back to your current install of windows.

You can now bootstrap the windows installer from windows itself - go to the folder you extracted the windows iso from, and run setup - be sure to select "new installation" rather than update.

[image].

This will do some stuff, reboot, and get you into the text mode setup. In text mode setup, once again, select new installation rather than repair.

Install xp into the *new* partition - this gives us somewhere to work on the old partition from. Unfortunately, since the old c: contains the bootloader and the windows installer files, getting rid of it is going to be slightly tricky.

Boot into the new install of windows, and we can start trying to work on clearing out the old install. Since this is a disposable install of xp we won't be using for long, don't bother with particularly correct settings or activation.

We need to do a few small changes to the second install - its still using the pagefile from our old drive so we need to get rid of that, go to system properties, set no pagefile on c: and automatic pagefile on 
[image]

This is where things get dangerous. If you mess up, you can be left with an unbootable system. We're in the working install right now - and the bootloader is in the other install. The first is a safer option, and should give you a fresh install of windows without too much risk. I'm currently trying to work out how to safely format a system disk, since if you're reformatting cause you have a virus, a simple clear out of the system may not be enough.

If you want a fresh install, rather than a real reformat, things are reasonably simple - delete the old files, other than reformatting, and run setup again from our working install. From the new install (on mine this is set as f: even on the new system), delete all the visible folders on the old system (Documents and settings, windows and program files are what I see on a fresh install. These need to go) . If you can see ntldr and boot.ini , leave them alone. You do *not* want to taunt the bootloader. Its the one thing we can't fix easily.

When you get into the text mode installer, select c: as your install location (no reformatting), and install it there, going through the install process and the settings again. We're almost done things the 'safe' way, and are in your new, fresh copy of windows. Now, we just need to get rid of our working copy of windows - we can simply remove it from boot.ini(startup and recovery from system properties), set the pagefile back to c: and delete and merge the partition with minitools.

I'll update the answer, when I actually manage to format c:, rather than getting a fresh copy up.

Comment: I forgot to upvote your answer before so I did now

Answer (score 2):

You should use the System Boot Menu to select your USB device manually.

According to the manual for your laptop model (found [here](http://support.ts.fujitsu.com/Download/ShowDescription.asp?Info=FTS&SoftwareGUID=07D8F753-12D8-4D6F-A028-6456CE047AE1&lng=COM)), you should press the F12 key during boot to access the boot menu.

Once in that menu, use the arrow keys to select your USB device and press ENTER.

If your device is not listed, you may need to double check that the USB device is bootable (like a linux rescue disk, or Windows PE).

It is also possible that the BIOS (accessed by pressing F2 during boot) contains settings pertaining to USB boot (such as 'USB emulation' settings). Unfortunately, the manual did not contain detailed information about specific BIOS settings, and merely said to press F1 for help while in the BIOS.

Comment: forgot to mention that it does not appear when I press f12 aswell, sorry for the missing information, I created the USB using ISO to USB

Comment: I would try using an article similar to this one: http://www.maximumpc.com/article/howtos/how_to_install_windows_7_beta_a_usb_key to create a USB to install Windows from (assuming that you are intending to install Windows)

Comment: I did follow many articles in creating the USB. None of the resulting USB flash drive's were shown in the boot menu

Answer (score 2):

The method is very simple and you can use without any hassles. Needless to say that your motherboard should support USB Boot feature to make use of the bootable USB drive.

---

Requirements:
1- *USB Flash Drive (Minimum 4GB) 
*Windows 7 or Vista installation files.
Follow the below steps to create bootable Windows 7/Vista USB drive using which you can install Windows 7/Vista easily.

---

1. Plug-in your USB flash drive to USB port and move all the contents from USB drive to a safe location on your system.
2. Open Command Prompt with admin rights. Use any of the below methods to open Command Prompt with admin rights.
   *Type cmd in Start menu search box and hit Ctrl+ Shift+ Enter.
   Or
   *Go to Start menu > All programs > Accessories, right click on Command Prompt and select Run as administrator.
3. You need to know about the USB drive a little bit. Type in the following commands in the command prompt:

   ---

   First type **DISKPART** and hit enter to see the below message.
   Next type **LIST DISK**  command and note down the Disk number (ex: Disk 1) of your USB flash drive. In the below screenshot my Flash Drive Disk no is Disk 1. 
   So below are the commands you need to type and execute one by one:
   SELECT DISK 1 
   CLEAN 
   CREATE PARTITION PRIMARY 
   SELECT PARTITION 1 
   ACTIVE 
   FORMAT FS=NTFS 
   (Format process may take few seconds) 
   ASSIGN 
   EXIT 
   Don’t close the command prompt as we need to execute one more command at the next step. Just minimize it.

   ---

Now Copy windows files from another computer in your USB 
Plug in USB in your laptop and boot it.

Enjoy

Comment: Did you read the question? Seriously. Have you read the fact that I already tried to boot from USB? Have you? I am looking for a solution for installing without the use of USB flash drive or DVD ROM. Both are not working. Your answer is quite informative but irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

*On my phone so poorly formatted and reviewed, just wanted to add my experience to hopefully help out john*

In response to can you install windows from within windows.

I have installed windows 7 from a mounted drive within xp successfully.

Would I advise it No if something goes wrong and you have no contingency plan you have an expensive brick.

---

The way it worked was I went through the pre-install process in xp then rebooted at the prompt and I was going straight into the install wizard I created a separate partition to my xp drive and installed their (was scared of deleting install files) then after install booted into windows 7 partition deleted the xp partition and was fine from their.

---

Footnotes: this was done with the dev pre-release of windows 7, this is risky and your results might differ

Comment: I am planning to install Windows XP from within XP. Is there another solution for this problem where DVD drive does not work and it does not recognize USB from the boot menu?

Comment: Is it feasible to remove the hdd and create a clone of it on a desktop?

Comment: Also the flash drive it's in a fat format not ntfs correct?

Comment: It's NTFS, I am not sure I understand what your other comment is saying

Comment: Reformat you flash drive to fat32 and try booting from USB again it could be a simple case of not being able to read ntfs

Comment: @john what you can do as a contingency plan is physically remove the hdd from the laptop plug it intoa ddesktop and create a disk image that you can restore to the hdd in the event of failure

Comment: The BIOS neither needs to support FAT32 nor NTFS to boot from it. It should just recognise a valid MBR with an active partition and load the boat loader. No file system (recognised or not) is needed for that. As to solving it:50-3's way might be the easiest. Remove drive. PLug in in another computer (or in an external eSATA enclosure). Install, sysprep. Return to the original computer. Boot.

Answer (score 0):

if you just copied the OS installation files, then that's the wrong procedure. you need to use a third party tool to do so. [Universal USB Creator](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/%E2%80%8E) has  pretty extensive list of OS.

Comment: I created the USB properly.....

Comment: I would not make a whole question because I simply copied the files to the USB. How dumb do you think I am? Your lucky I can't downvote you because I've given my rep as bounty